# cin running only once inside while loop

Tags: c++, while-loop, cin

I have seen another post with nearly the same title but it didn't help at all since they had a mistake in there code. I just want to get as many values as the client puts in and add them but it only takes the first input

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int issa_def() {
    int issa[] = {};
    int half_ans_issa[] = {};
    int i  = 0;
    int cn = 0;
    while(true) {
        cout << "enter prices of items ordered by issa: ";
        cin >> cn;
        if(cn == 111) {
            break;
        }
        else {
        issa[i] = cn;
        }
        i++;
        cin.clear();
    }
    int a = 0;
    for(int i = 0;i <= sizeof(issa);i+=2) {
        int ans = issa[i] + issa[i+1];
        half_ans_issa[a] = ans;
        a++;
        cout << issa[i] << "\n" << issa[i+1] << "\n";
    }
    a = 0;
    cout << half_ans_issa[a];
}
int main() {
    issa_def();

}
```

here is the output after printing the values of the first and second input i put in and the sum

```
C:\Users\akram\Documents\code>a.exe
enter prices of items ordered by issa: 5
enter prices of items ordered by issa: 5
enter prices of items ordered by issa: 111
first input:5
second input:0
output:5
```

note: 111 is the exit code

i turned on compiler warnings as stated by user –πάντα ῥεῖ and i got the error

```
dahra.cpp:23:18: warning: comparison between signed and unsigned integer express
ions [-Wsign-compare]
  for(int i = 0;i <= sizeof(issa);i+=2)
```

Comment: Your code has undefined behavior. Where's your `return` statement in that function? Switch all compiler warnings on before askineg here next time please.

Comment: may i ask how would the compiler warnings would help me in this situation

Comment: You'll get a warning about that missing `return` statement. Put one there.

Comment: Next problem are zero sized arrays: `int half_ans_issa[] = {};` more UB all the way. I'D recommend you' start with a [good book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list).

Comment: Use a `std::vector` when you need a dynamic array whose size is not known at compile-time and will grow at runtime.

Comment: i do give it a value later on but i just wrote it this way as the size is user defined i cannot state the size beforehand

Comment: ill try the std::vector and will reply with an answer

Comment: @TsutsuiTsutsun you can't use arrays like that. They need to have a fixed size at compile-time. Use `std::vector` instead.

Comment: i got it the nature of arrays do not allow this and vectors are better at this so i will learn vectors and change my code thank you

Comment: What is the size of your arrays? You initialize them with  {} so they are just an int* without any memory allocation. As soon as you insert values to issa[i] you will overflow. For a similar reason you cannot iterate from 0 to sizeof(issa) (including the latter). First, sizeof gives you the size in bytes, not the number of array elements. Second, should sizeof works as you expect, you iterate through (n+1) elements, not (n). Finally, if the array has an odd number of elements, you access memory outside the array (issa[i+1]). You should use std::vector to get an arbitrary number of inputs.

Comment: @xuman can you post your comment as an answer so that i can flag it as the answer thank you all for your help it really helped me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is the size of your arrays? You initialize them with `{}` so they are just an `int*` without any memory allocation. As soon as you insert values to `issa[i]` you will overflow.

For a similar reason you cannot iterate from 0 to `sizeof(issa)` (including the latter). First, `sizeof` gives you the size in bytes, not the number of array elements. Second, should `sizeof` works as you expect, you iterate through (n+1) elements, not (n). Finally, if the array has an odd number of elements, you access memory outside the array (`issa[i+1]`). You should use `std::vector` to get an arbitrary number of inputs.

Finally, you should have a `return` of your `issa_def` function.

Wrapping up, when you insert elements in your array you should use

`issa.push_back(cn)`

And, when iterating through `issa`, you should consider even/odd arrays, as well as the appropriate size of the array:

```
for(int i = 0; i < issa.size() - 1; i += 2) {
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should flush *cin* buffer with `cin.clear(); cin.ignore();`

`cin.clear()` clears the internal state of stream, this way you avoid errors. Then `cin.ignore()` ignores everything until the next line (that's what you want)

Comment: i tried that but i didnt work because the issue was something else

Comment: clear the buffer right after cin, that break; can interupt the loop before it get flushed

Comment: will include for sure after i edit and fix the code to actually work since cin did work fine and get the input but the input was handled in a wrong way

Comment: ah, and the warning just says you are comparing a sizeof(unsigned int) with int(signed int)

Comment: yes it was caused by using 0 fixed sized arrays

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you have to define array issa with a constant size. Here you have defined an empty array. So you cannot access elements with issa[i] and assign a new value. For this purpose, you can use a vector array.

```
vector<int> issa;
int temp;
cin>>temp;
issa.push_back(temp);
```

2nd You have to write a return statement.

Warning: comparison between signed and unsigned

Here, the problem with your code is you are comparing a signed integer with an unsigned integer. sizeof(issa) returns an unsigned integer.

you can fix this by declaring a signed integer like

```
int n = sizeof(issa);
for(int i = 0;i <n ;i+=2) {
```